# Java truststore root certificate not trusted of [myserver.mydomain.com]

Tags: java, ssl, openssl, keytool, truststore

I am running into some difficulty trying to connect to a server using a custom java truststore, where I get the following error when I try to connect. I have very little experience using java to connect via SSL so I'm concerned there's just something I'm unaware of causing an issue:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertificateException: root certificate not trusted of [myserver.mydomain.com]
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1884)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:276)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:270)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1341)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:153)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:868)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:804)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1016)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1312)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1339)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1323)
    at org.jiv
```

The connection requires both a keystore and a truststore which I have created in the following manner:

Keystore:

- Generated a private key on the client (`openssl genrsa -out mykey.key 4096`)
- Generated a self-signed CSR /w a challenge password (`openssl req -new -key mykey.key -out mykey.csr`)
- Generatd a self-signed cert public-key pair certificate (`openssl req -x509 -days 365 -key mykey.key -in mykey.csr -out mykey.cer`)
- Generated a PKCS12 file from the private key (`openssl pkcs12 -export -out mykey.p12 -inkey mykey.key -in mykey.cer`)
- Added the new PKCS12 file to a new keystore (`keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore mykey.p12 -destkeystore mykeystore.jks  -srcstoretype PKCS12`)
- Added the server's public cert to the keystore after convering it from `pem` to `der` (`keytool -import -alias mnt1 -keystore mykeystore.jks -file puiblicserver.der`)

Truststore:

- Added the same public key from the server to a new truststore (`keytool -import -alias root -keystore truststore.jks -file puiblicserver.der`)

---

From there I upload the mykey.cer to the server's trusted certificate store. One thing I noticed is that when I inspected the connection using my jar file (`java -Djavax.net.debug=ssl,handshake -jar myjar.jar myserver.mydomain.com User truststore.jks <PW> mykeystore.jks <PW>`) is that the server is actually signed by a Digicert Intermediate cert. So I also added both the intermediate and root certs from Digicert into the truststore (not the keystore) but that does not work.

However, if I cat the intermediate and root certs and use them in an openssl connection from the client to the server it successfully connects, which leads me to believe it's something to do with the java truststore.

---

Edit: I'm calling the connection in java with the following:

```
TLSConfiguration config = new TLSConfiguration();
    config.setHosts(hostnames);
    config.setUserName(username);
    config.setGroup(Group.EPS.value());
    config.setKeystorePath(keystoreFilename);
    config.setKeystorePassphrase(keystorePassword);
    config.setTruststorePath(truststoreFilename);
    config.setTruststorePassphrase(truststorePassword);
```

Example: `java -Djavax.net.debug=ssl,handshake -jar myjar.jar myserver.mydomain.com User truststore.jks <PW> mykeystore.jks <PW>`

Answer (score 0):

It's not really clear from your question which trust store you are using. Did you load your self signed certificate into the default trust store with something like this?

```
keytool -import -trustcacerts -keystore cacerts -storepass changeit -noprompt -alias yourAliasName -file path\to\certificate.cer
```

If not, you need to tell Java which trust store to use. If you don't it will use the default (which doesn't have your self signed cert in it). You need to do this:

```
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=<path to your trusstore>.jks -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=<your password>
```

Note: if you set a trust store via -D parameters your code will trust ONLY CAs in that trust store.

To specify which keystore to use you can add these java opts:

```
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=<path to your keystore>.jks -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=<your keystore password>
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, I'm specifying the keystore / truststore in my jar (I've edited my post to include this)